# Inserting into mysql/php difficulties

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make an auction site and make it so I can update it in mysql table, but It won't update a thing in mysql table. I get a php error log, and all the errors I get are from

```
t-2012 17:02:46] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: auctionnum in /devel/cgreenheld/projects/Asgn2/auction.php on line 21

[04-Oct-2012 17:02:46] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: reserve_met in /devel/cgreenheld/projects/Asgn2/auction.php on line 116

[04-Oct-2012 17:02:46] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: reserve in /devel/cgreenheld/projects/Asgn2/auction.php on line 123

[04-Oct-2012 17:02:46] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: highest_bid in /devel/cgreenheld/projects/Asgn2/auction.php on line 123

[04-Oct-2012 17:02:46] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: highest_bid in /devel/cgreenheld/projects/Asgn2/auction.php on line 123
[04-Oct-2012 17:02:46] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: auctionnum in /devel/cgreenheld/projects/Asgn2/auction.php on line 124

[04-Oct-2012 17:02:46] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: title in /devel/cgreenheld/projects/Asgn2/auction.php on line 130

[04-Oct-2012 17:02:46] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: bio in /devel/cgreenheld/projects/Asgn2/auction.php on line 131

[04-Oct-2012 17:02:46] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: reserve_met in /devel/cgreenheld/projects/Asgn2/auction.php on line 133

[04-Oct-2012 17:02:46] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: reserve in /devel/cgreenheld/projects/Asgn2/auction.php on line 134
```

I have quite a bit of code so i'll try to narrow it down to the bits that i feel are relevant. It's all quite basic atm, but I just want to make it be able to insert things into the mysql table.
So this is the form they enter to insert the auction (this works fine)

```
<h2>Create a new Auction!</h2>
    <?php
        echo "<form method='post' action='createauction.php' enctype=multipart/form-data>";
    echo '<fieldset class="register">';
    echo"<h2>Auction Properties</h2>";
        echo "<ul>";
                echo '<li><label for="Title">Auction Title:</label> <input type="text" name="Title" id="Title"></li>';
                echo '<li><label for="Bio">Auction Description </label> <input type="text" name="Bio" id="Bio"></li>';
                echo '<li><label for="Reserve">Reserve</label><input type="text" name="Reserve" id="Reserve"></li>';
                echo '<li id="contentbox">Category:</li>';
                echo '<li><select name="Category"></li>';
                echo '<li><option value="clothing">Clothing</option></li>';
                echo '<li><option value="electronics">Electronics</option></li>';
                echo '<li><option value="living">Living</option></li>';
                echo '<li><input type="submit" value="Create"></li>';
                echo "</ul>";
    echo "</fieldset>";
    echo "</form>";
    ?>
```

This is inserts it into the table (this also works fine)

```
<?php
    $clean_title = $_POST['Title'];
    $clean_bio = $_POST['Bio'];
    $clean_category = $_POST['Category'];
    $username = $_SESSION['user'];
    $reserve = $_POST['Reserve'];
    $insert = 'Insert INTO Auctions(closingtime, Title, Bio, Category, Username, reserver) VALUES (NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY,  "'.$clean_title.'", "'.$clean_bio.'", "'.$clean_category.'", "'.$_SESSION['user'].'", "'.$reserve.'")'; 
    $result = $conn->query($insert);
    $auction_query = "select Auctionno from Auctions ORDER BY Auctionno";
    $result2 = $conn->query($auction_query);
        while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $auctionnum = $row['Auctionno'];
        }
?>

<p>Your auction has been started click <a href="auction.php?id=<?php echo $auctionnum;?>">here</a> to view it.
            </p>
```

Which takes us to the page to view our auction
Then we get to our auction page, where

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  $auctionnum = $_GET['id'];
 }else{
  header("Location: browse.php");
  exit();
 }

$query = 'SELECT * FROM Auctions WHERE Auctionno = "'.$auctionnum.'";';
$result = $conn->query($query);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $auctionnum = $row['Auctionno'];
    $title = $row['Title'];
    $bio = $row['Bio'];
    $category = $row['Category'];
    $reserve = $row['reserver'];
    $reserve_met = $row['reserve_MET'];
    $highest_bid = $row['highest_bid'];
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
            <!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="IEstyle.css"/>
    <script>
    document.createElement('nav');
    document.createElement('section');
    document.createElement('footer'):
    document.createElement('header');
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
        <title>Bargin Bin: A place where Kiwis can buy and sell!</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="auction.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <header>
        <img src="logo.gif" alt="Bargin Bin Logo">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="login.php"><b>Login</b></a></li>
        <li><a href="register.php"><b>Register</b></a></li>
        </ul>
        <?php
            if($_SESSION['authorisation'] == 'knownuser') {
                if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        echo '<ul class="log">';
        echo '<li><h4>You are logged in as '.$_SESSION['user'].'</h4></li>';
        echo '<li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>';
        echo "</ul>";
            }
        }
        else {
        echo "<h4>You are not logged in</h4>";
        }
        ?>
    </header>
    <nav>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="browse.php"><b>Browse</b></a></li>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['authorisation'])) {
    if($_SESSION['authorisation'] == 'knownuser') {
    echo '<li><a href="account.php">MyAccount</a></li>';
    }
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
    echo '<li><a href="admin.php">Admin</a></li>';
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['authorisation'])) {
    if($_SESSION['authorisation'] = 'knownuser') {
    echo '<li><b>MyAuction</b></li>';
    }
    }
    ?>
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <section>   
    <div id="bidbar">
    <?php
echo "<form action=\"bid.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<div id=\"bidbar\">";
if($reserve_met == 0){
  echo "<span>Starting bid:$</span>";
}else{
  echo "<span>Min next bid: $</span>";
}
?>

<input id="bidinput" type="text" name="bid" value="<?php echo $reserve > $highest_bid ? $reserve : $highest_bid + 1;?>" size="4">
<input type="hidden" name="auction_number" value="<?php echo $auctionnum;?>">
<input type="submit" id="bidbutton" value="click here to bid">
</div><!-- //bidbar -->
</form>

<?php
    echo "<h1 id=\"auctiontitle\">Auction Title: $title </h1>";
    echo "<p id=\auctionbio\">Auction Description: $bio</p>";
    echo "<div id=\"infobar\">";
    if($reserve_met == 0){
        echo "<span>Start Price: \$$reserve</span>";
        echo "</br>";
         echo "<span id=\"reserve\">No reserve</span>";
        }else{
        echo "<span>Highest Bid:\$$highest_bid</span>";
        echo "<span id=\"reserve\">Reserve Met</span>";
    }

?>
    </section>
    <hr>
    <footer>Courtney Greenheld Web Design 2012 Ltd.</footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And then this is my page to process the bid.

```
if(isset($_POST['bid']) && isset($_POST['auctionnum'])) {
  $clean_bid = $_POST['bid'];
echo $clean_bid;
  $auctionnum = $_POST['auctionnum'];
echo $auctionnum;
  $bidder = $_SESSION['user'];
echo $bidder;
}else{
  header("Location: auction.php");
  exit();
}
$query_highest_bid = 'SELECT highest_bid FROM Auctions WHERE Auctionno = "'.$auctionnum.'";';
$result = $conn->query($insert);
$highest_array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$highest_bid = $highest_array[0];
$query1 = 'UPDATE Auctions SET highest_bid = "'.$clean_bid.'" WHERE Auctionno = "'.$auctionnum.'";';
$result1 = $conn->query($query1);
$query2 = 'UPDATE Auctions SET highest_bidder = "'.$bidder.'" WHERE Auctionno = "'.$auctionnum.'";';
$result2 = $conn->query($query2);
$query3 = 'UPDATE Auctions SET highest_bidder = "'.$bidder.'" WHERE Auctionno = "'.$auctionnum.'";';
$result3 = $conn->query($query3);
$query4 = 'INSERT INTO BiddingUsers(Auctionno, Username, Bid) VALUES("'.$auctionnum.'" , "'.$bidder.'", "'.$clean_bid.'");';
$result4 = $conn->query($query4);
header("Location: auction.php?id=$auctionnum");

?>
```

I'm not really sure exactly where it's going wrong, i think the mysql_fetch_array is a problem, I don't usually use that.. But i'm very stumped as to whats going wrong.
And I haven't santistised my inputs yet, but i am aware of them.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to **READ** the error message? It specifies what's wrong with your code.

Comment: As zerkms said, read the error messages. These are fairly simple; they even give you the line number. (whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: It must also be said, your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. You will get hacked in a matter of time if you don't use SQL prepared statements or at the very least quote all of your input.

Comment: Yes I have read the error message.. I don't understand why it is giving me the error message when I have initialised the variables..

Comment: @courtney: if php says it's not initialized - then you didn't

Comment: Why do you have a while loop to process the results of the query when it apparently only returns one row (you're overwriting the same variables each time through the loop)? Whenever I see that (too often, IMHO), it's a clue that the programmer simply copied code without understanding what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

**Where's the connection to your database ? ($conn) I cannot see it being initialized.**

Also, make sure you enable "`display_errors`", by adding the following code to the top of your file. this way you can debug your code properly, after that, comment or simply remove it.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

As a side-note to your coding style I would recommend using `EOF` instead of multiple `echo`

EX:
you have:

```
echo "<h1 id=\"auctiontitle\">Auction Title: $title </h1>";
    echo "<p id=\auctionbio\">Auction Description: $bio</p>";
    echo "<div id=\"infobar\">";
```

I would recommend:

```
$pagina = <<< EOF
<h1 id="auctiontitle">Auction Title: $title </h1>
<p id=\auctionbio">Auction Description: $bio</p>
<div id="infobar">
more html...
EOF;
echo $pagina ;
```

It's easier to write and read and more error proof because you don't have to escape everything.

Comment: Now, with the display_errors ON (on every file) read the first error that appears on the page your loading and past it here.

Comment: Our security settings on our server don't let me use that.. sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry to know that, you should be able to turn php errors on and off on, I would say, 99% of the hosting providers. Get a decent hosting company so you can work efficiently and always turn errors ON when your coding, it's foul not doing so. GL

Comment: Before php 5.4 you should use E_ALL | E_STRICT

Answer (score 0):

This is because those variable not defined before using them. Use `error_reporting(0)` at the top of aution.php file or assign empty values for the variables like,

```
$auctionnum=$title=$bio=$category=$reserve=$reserve_met=$highest_bid="";
```

**Reason:**

For example,

```
 $temp="test";
 echo $temp;
```

In above code `$temp` variable assigned a value. so it won't give you any notices. but look at the following code:

```
echo $tt;
```

In this code `$tt` variable has not defined/assigned any value before using it. so it will issue a notice like you mentioned. lets go to your code, in the auction.php when the following query executed,

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM Auctions WHERE Auctionno = "'.$auctionnum.'";';
```

you will have the values for the variables like `$auctionnum`, `$title`,`$bio`,`$category`,
`$reserve`,`$reserve_met`,`$highest_bid` . if the query has no records then it is unassigned and you'll see php notices.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use variable not defined before using them.
Please on lines where get errors use instead of:

```
 $clean_title = $_POST['Title'];
 $clean_bio = $_POST['Bio'];
 ....
```

please use

```
$clean_title = (isset($_POST['Title'])?$_POST['Title']:"");
$clean_bio = (isset($_POST['Bio'])?$_POST['Bio']:"");
....
```

it can be used for others variables too,example:
instead of

```
$title
```

use

```
(isset($title)?$title:"")
```